# Transferring front end data from HTML checkboxes to backend django in forms.py/views.py/urls.py

Tags: python, html, django

I have a bunch of checkboxes on my HTML page and want to store whether a checkbox was ticked or not in backend django. My current HTML code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="activism" value="Yes">Activism & advocacy
```

I don't know how to modify my forms.py/urls.py/views.py to store whether a particular checkbox was ticked or not. Thank you very much.

Comment: what about sending a `post request` containing all the checkbox data via a form to django? have you tested it?

Comment: I am very new to web development. Could you please post snippets of code explaining the above method? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you are, it's not the best way to. Since you are new to django, this will work. Alongside you're learning, take the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/) as guide

```
<form action='url' method='post'> {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="checkbox" name="activism" value="Yes">Activism & advocacy
   <input type='submit' value="submit" />
</form>
```

python view

```
def viewName(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      # You have access to data inside request.POST
      activism = request.POST.get('activism')
      if activism:
           pass # Activism is checked
```